# Call function A if leave page clicked else function B when I am closing a browser window alert

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

If I click reload I need to fire a function else another function. Does any such function exist ?

I want to delete all login details when window will close. else everything will remain same.

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload

Comment: There is not really much you can do to tell the difference. onunload and onbeforeunload fire for both. Cleaning up session data on server really should be with session timeouts.